# How to load json nested data into bigquery

Tags: python, json, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I'm trying to load the json data from an API into bigquery table on GCP however I got an issue that the json data seem to miss a square bracket so it got an error '"Repeated record with name trip_update added outside of an array."}]'. I don't know how
Here is the data sample:

```
{
    "header": {
        "gtfs_realtime_version": "1.0",
        "timestamp": 1607630971
    },
    "entity": [
        {
            "id": "65.5.17-120-cm1-1.18.O",
            "trip_update": {
                "trip": {
                    "trip_id": "65.5.17-120-cm1-1.18.O",
                    "start_time": "18:00:00",
                    "start_date": "20201210",
                    "schedule_relationship": "SCHEDULED",
                    "route_id": "17-120-cm1-1"
                },
                "stop_time_update": [
                    {
                        "stop_sequence": 1,
                        "departure": {
                            "delay": 0
                        },
                        "stop_id": "8220B1351201",
                        "schedule_relationship": "SCHEDULED"
                    },
                    {
                        "stop_sequence": 23,
                        "arrival": {
                            "delay": 2340
                        },
                        "departure": {
                            "delay": 2340
                        },
                        "stop_id": "8260B1025301",
                        "schedule_relationship": "SCHEDULED"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is a schema and code:
schema

```
    [
        { "name":"header",
           "type": "record",
           "fields": [
                {   "name":"gtfs_realtime_version",
                    "type": "string",
                    "description": "version of speed specification"
                },
                { "name": "timestamp",
                    "type": "integer",
                    "description": "The moment where this dataset was generated on server e.g. 1593102976"
                }
            ]

        },
        {"name":"entity",
            "type": "record",
            "mode": "REPEATED",
            "description": "Multiple entities can be included in the feed",
            "fields": [
                {"name":"id",
                    "type": "string",
                    "description": "unique identifier for the entity"
                },
                {"name": "trip_update",
                     "type": "struct",
                     "mode": "REPEATED",
                    "description": "Data about the realtime departure delays of a trip. At least one of the fields trip_update, vehicle, or alert must be provided - all these fields cannot be empty.",
                    "fields": [
                         { "name":"trip",
                            "type": "record",
                            "mode": "REPEATED",
                            "fields": [
                                {"name": "trip_id",
                                    "type": "string",
                                    "description": "selects which GTFS entity (trip) will be affected"
                                },
                                { "name":"start_time",
                                    "type": "string",
                                    "description": "The initially scheduled start time of this trip instance 13:30:00"
                                },
                                { "name":"start_date",
                                    "type": "string",
                                    "description": "The start date of this trip instance in YYYYMMDD format. Whether start_date is required depends on the type of trip: e.g. 20200625"
                                },
                                { "name":"schedule_relationship",
                                    "type": "string",
                                    "description": "The relation between this trip and the static schedule e.g. SCHEDULED"
                                },
                                { "name":"route_id",
                                    "type": "string",
                                    "description": "The route_id from the GTFS feed that this selector refers to e.g. 10-263-e16-1"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                { "name":"stop_time_update",
                    "type": "record",
                    "mode": "REPEATED",
                    "description": "Updates to StopTimes for the trip (both future, i.e., predictions, and in some cases, past ones, i.e., those that already happened). The updates must be sorted by stop_sequence, and apply for all the following stops of the trip up to the next specified stop_time_update. At least one stop_time_update must be provided for the trip unless the trip.schedule_relationship is CANCELED - if the trip is canceled, no stop_time_updates need to be provided.",
                    "fields": [
                        {"name":"stop_sequence",
                            "type": "string",
                            "description": "Must be the same as in stop_times.txt in the corresponding GTFS feed e.g 3"
                        },
                        { "name":"arrival",
                            "type": "record",
                            "mode": "REPEATED",
                            "fields": [
                                { "name":"delay",
                                    "type": "string",
                                    "description": "Delay (in seconds) can be positive (meaning that the vehicle is late) or negative (meaning that the vehicle is ahead of schedule). Delay of 0 means that the vehicle is exactly on time e.g 5"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        { "name": "departure",
                            "type": "record",
                            "mode": "REPEATED",
                            "fields": [
                                { "name":"delay",
                                    "type": "integer"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {  "name":"stop_id",
                            "type": "string",
                            "description": "Must be the same as in stops.txt in the corresponding GTFS feed e.g. 8430B2552301"
                        },
                        {"name":"schedule_relationship",
                            "type": "string",
                            "description": "The relation between this StopTime and the static schedule e.g. SCHEDULED , SKIPPED or NO_DATA"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

function (following google guideline https://cloud.google.com/solutions/streaming-data-from-cloud-storage-into-bigquery-using-cloud-functions?authuser=2#before-you-begin)

```
def _insert_into_bigquery(bucket_name, file_name):
    blob = CS.get_bucket(bucket_name).blob(file_name)
    row = json.loads(blob.download_as_string())
    table = BQ.dataset(BQ_DATASET).table(BQ_TABLE)
    errors = BQ.insert_rows_json(table,
                                 json_rows=row,
                                 ignore_unknown_values=True,
                                 retry=retry.Retry(deadline=30))
    if errors != []:
        raise BigQueryError(errors)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your schema definition is wrong. `trip_update` isn't a struct repeated, but a record nullable (or not, but not repeated)

```
                    {"name": "trip_update",
                     "type": "record",
                     "mode": "NULLABLE",
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the limitations in [loading JSON data from GCS](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-json) to BigQuery is that it does not support maps or dictionaries in JSON.
I believe that your "trip_update" and "trip" fields must contain an array of values (indicated by square brackets), the same as you did for "stop_time_update".

```
"trip_update": [
    {
    "trip": [
        {
            "trip_id
```

I am not sure that will be enough though to load your data flawlessly.
Your example row has many newline characters in the middle of your JSON row, and when you are loading data from JSON files, the rows must be newline delimited. BigQuery expects newline-delimited JSON files to contain a single record per line (the parser is trying to interpret each line as a separate JSON row) ([Reference](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data#choosing_a_data_ingestion_method#:%7E:text=Embedded%20newlines)).
[Example](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-json#loading_nested_and_repeated_json_data) of how your JSON data file should look like.

Comment: Yes the json data missing a square bracket after trip_update but it is the original format that I request from a public API  (https://developer.nationaltransport.ie/api-details#api=gtfsr&operation=gtfsr). Therefore I'm looking for solution that could read the given format